# RTP Proxy code debugging using GDB

Tags: proxy, gdb, rtp

I integrated `rtp` proxy with `kamailio` successfully but there are few issue I am facing.

I downloaded source code of `RTP` proxy, and compiled

and I am starting with the command,

```
./src/rtpproxy   -F -l <IP> -m 20000 -M 30000 -s udp:127.0.0.1:7722 -d DBUG:LOG_LOCAL3 start
```

but while stopping I am not able to stop the `rtp` proxy, other then killing the process any other option ?

Also want to check the Code flow of `rtp` proxy code using `GDB`. But after putting breakpoint also it not hitting the breakpoint. Can anyone suggest how to use `GDB` in case of `RTP` proxy code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you install rtpproxy from package, then you have /etc/init.d/rtpproxy script that you can use to start/stop rtpproxy, or the equivalent service file for systemd.

If you want to use a version compiled from sources, then using kill  or killall rtpproxy is a common practice. To get the pid, you can provide -p /path/to/pid/file when starting rtpproxy and then look inside, or use ps command to check the process table and see the pid value for rtpproxy application.

For gdb, have in mind that rtpproxy creates few threads, so check the manual of gdb for troubleshooting multi-threading applications.